# Creating registration program in java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem.

I'm  trying to create a registration program using text files in java.

I wrote some code to do registration but at first my program should check if username is exists in text file or not.

If username is exists then the program asks user to enter new one.

But there is some error in my code i don't know, it is not checking if username exists or not.

here is my code:

```
                System.out.println("Registration Page");
                System.out.println("NOTE: your username is a unique one so it cannot be changed.");
                System.out.printf("Username: ");
                String user = input.next();
                System.out.printf("Password: ");
                String pass = input.next();
                System.out.printf("Confirm Password: ");
                String conf = input.next();
                int length = pass.length();
                int passInt = Integer.parseInt(pass);
                int confInt = Integer.parseInt(conf);
                if(length < 6)
                    System.out.println("Too short password, password must be 6 characters or more");
                else
                {
                if(passInt == confInt)
                {
                Scanner z = null;
                try{
                z = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt"));
                boolean checkname = false;
                while(z.hasNext())
                {
                String a = z.next();
                int b = z.nextInt();
                if(a == null ? user == null : a.equals(user))
                checkname = true;
                }
                if(checkname)
                System.out.println("Username is already exists and used, please type another one");
                else
                {
                Formatter x = null;
                try{
                FileWriter f = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt", true);
                x = new Formatter(f);
                x.format("%s %s%n",user.toUpperCase(),pass);
                System.out.println("You registered succesfully");
                x.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                }                    
                catch(Exception e){}
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("Password and confirm password are not matching");
                }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the output of the error?

Comment: you don't understand what i mean by error. i mean that program insert the record in the text file without checking if username exists before or not. that what i mean by error.

Answer (score 2):

So instead of using Scanner to open and read the file, try using BufferedReader and Writer respectively for the reading and writing. In the code below we are reading through the file and if the name exists it will change your boolean to true and will then throw your error, otherwise it will complete the registration. It also will write the new information. Now one thing you may want to add is a way to loop back to the top if the information is invalid.

Also as a side not, for better cross OS functionality, you should use File.separator() which will do the same thing.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Registration Page");
        System.out.println("NOTE: your username is a unique one so it cannot be changed.");
        System.out.printf("Username: ");
        String user = input.next();
        System.out.printf("Password: ");
        String pass = input.next();
        System.out.printf("Confirm Password: ");
        String conf = input.next();
        int length = pass.length();
        int passInt = Integer.parseInt(pass);
        int confInt = Integer.parseInt(conf);
        File file = new File("C:"+File.separator + "Users"+File.separator + "فاطمة"+File.separator + "Downloads"+File.separator + "accounts.txt");
        if (length < 6) {
            System.out.println("Too short password, password must be 6 characters or more");
        } else {
            if (passInt == confInt) {

                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String current;
                    boolean checkname = false;
                    while ((current = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if(current.equalsIgnoreCase(user)){
                            checkname = true;
                    }
                }
                if (checkname) {
                    System.out.println("Username is already exists and used, please type another one");
                } else {
                    Formatter x = null;
                    try {
                        FileWriter f = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(f);
                        bw.write(user);
                        bw.close();
                        x = new Formatter(f);
                        x.format("%s %s%n", user.toUpperCase(), pass);
                        System.out.println("You registered succesfully");
                        x.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Password and confirm password are not matching");
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found what is the problem with my code:

the problem is that the username is found in the text file in this format:

```
JOHN 114477
SARAH 887755
```

The username is in uppercase letters and when i enter new username it's written in lower case letters so when searching for username in the text file the program compares name in lowercase letters with a name in uppercase letters that are not matching and so it allows me to enter the same username that exists before.

the correct solution is by editing this line and adding toUpperCase(); to it like this:

```
String user = input.next().toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Take a look at the code I posted above. The above code uses a more common reading method and will not throw an error unless you want for case size.